# Circular dependency - when does it terminate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am having trouble understanding how python manages `import`s.

Let's say I have the following application structure:

```
application/
- application.py
- model/
-- __init__.py
-- user.py
```

Let's say that the `application.py` file imports the model module after creating the db like so:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(application) 
import model
```

Let's also say the the `model` module imports the `user.py` file like so:

```
import user
```

Finally, let's say that the `user.py` file imports the `db` instance from the `application.py` file like so:

```
from application import db
```

This seems like a circular dependency to me as the `application.py` file indirectly requires the `user.py` file but the `user.py` file requires the `db` instance from the `application.py` file.

I know that this code does work as I tested it but can someone explain exactly how Python handles this, and when it terminates the cyclical cycle.

To summarize the problem, when `user.py` file imports `db` from the `application.py` file it seems to me like it would also call the import `model` module which creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular imports themselves are not necessarily a problem. Only circular *dependencies* are. You can see how the circular import is resolved with some simple experimentation:

In `mymod1.py`

```
import sys
print("1. from mymod1:", [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")])
import mymod2
print("2. from mymod1:", [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")])
```

In `mymod2.py`

```
import sys
print("1. from mymod2:", [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")])
import mymod3
print("2. from mymod2:", [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")])
```

In `mymod3.py`

```
import sys
print("1. from mymod3:", [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")])
import mymod1
print("2. from mymod3:", [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")])
```

Now we have a cycle `mymod1 -> mymod2 -> mymod3 -> mymod1`. Enter the REPL and watch what happens:

```
>>> import mymod1
1. from mymod1: ['mymod1']  # before mymod1 imported mymod2. note mymod1 is already there!
1. from mymod2: ['mymod1', 'mymod2']  # in mymod2 now, before importing mymod3
1. from mymod3: ['mymod1', 'mymod2', 'mymod3']  # before mymod3 imports mymod1
2. from mymod3: ['mymod1', 'mymod2', 'mymod3']  # mymod3 exit
2. from mymod2: ['mymod1', 'mymod2', 'mymod3']  # mymod2 exit
2. from mymod1: ['mymod1', 'mymod3', 'mymod2']  # mymod1 exit
```

The key insight here is that the module instance itself is already present in `sys.modules` before it has completed execution. That means it can be imported again and it will return the existing object, without needing to execute all the module-level code again.

It's natural for components within submodules of a package to have interdependencies. Issues mostly arise when module-scoped code starts actually *doing* things like trying to connect to a db, so try to avoid scripting anything directly in the module level.

The cause of circular import *errors* are when something in the module namespace is needed before the module has finished initializing. In this case, the module itself exists but the name you're trying to access might not be there yet.

```
# mymod.py
import sys
print("var" in vars(sys.modules["mymod"]))
var = "I'm a name in mymod namespace"
print("var" in vars(sys.modules["mymod"]))
```

Importing `mymod` would print `False` and then `True`, the module's namespace itself is still being mutated as the import is in the process of executing.

An astute reader may have noticed that `mymod2` and `mymod3` switched places in the output:

```
2. from mymod2: ['mymod1', 'mymod2', 'mymod3']
2. from mymod1: ['mymod1', 'mymod3', 'mymod2']
                           |_____ wtf? _____|
```

This is actually no accident! The import machinery, as a final step in loading an module, pulls the actual module out of `sys.modules`. If you check again within the REPL, `mymod1` will now be last.

```
>>> import mymod1
...
>>> [x for x in sys.modules if x.startswith("mymod")]
['mymod3', 'mymod2', 'mymod1']
```

I won't describe why the import system does that, because it's not really relevant to the question, but users interested to know the reasons should see [this mailing list post from Guido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-May/014969.html).